# GNU getopt optarg null

Tags: c, getopts

In order to understand how to use getopt I used the example from [gnus manual example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt). I reduced it to the case I was interested, as stated below:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *cvalue = NULL;
  int c;

  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "c")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'c':
        cvalue = optarg;
        break;
      }

  printf ("cvalue = %s\n", cvalue);

  return 0;
}
```

As you see, I'm only interested in the examples case '$(testopt -c foo)'. Now, when trying to execute the above, my 'optarg' is (null). 
Why?? Or maybe better; how can i fix this?

Comment: Doesn't your optstring need to be `"c:"` if you expect option `-c` to take an argument?

Comment: Reduced the example by one wafer-thin bit too much.

Comment: @steeldriver oh, nice, this was the problem. I just looked into the manual again and there it says... 
thanks :)